# Positioning three divs with css

Tags: html, css, layout

I have three `divs`:

```
<div id="login" />
<div id="content" />  
<div id="menu" />
```

How would I define the CSS styles (without touching the HTML) to have the `menu-div` as the left column, the `login-div` in the right column and the `content-div` also in the right column but below the `login-div`.

The `width` of every div is fixed, but the `height` isn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#menu {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px;
}
#content, #login {
  margin-left:120px;
}
```

Why this way?  The menu coming last in the markup makes it tough.  You might also be able to float both content and login right, and added a clear:right to content, but I think this might be your best bet.  Without seeing the bigger picture, it is hard to give a solution that will definitely work in your case.

---

EDIT: This seems to work as well:

```
#content, #login {
  float:right;
  clear:right
}
```

---

More thoughts:  The absolute positioning won't work (or won't work well) if you want to have the columns in a centered layout.  The float seems to work - as long as you can get any border-between-columns type requirements to pan out with the float solution, you might be better off choosing that.  Then again, if the site is supposed to be left align, I think that the absolute method would work very well for your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the floating-approach. The clear:right in the content-div did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Floats away... not perfect.  [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134125/positioning-three-divs-with-css#134162) seems a better solution.

```css
#login {
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#content {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}

#menu {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="login">Login</div>
<div id="content">Content</div>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
```